# Google Chat API - PHP

Tags: php, api, google-chat

I would like to integrate chat functionality in my PHP website with Google Chat API,
I checked the link https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest

Here, with these APIs, I want to create rooms between two users, sending messages to each other in a room, but I did not find the right way to do so. are there any preferable docs? (I reviewed official docs, seems not much useful)

Comment: I agree, the badly documented API seems to favour only Python for setting up API access. Surely we should be given pure HTTP and JSON examples ? We can then use the REST api on multiple environments ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create rooms between users, I recommend you to take a look at [`spaces`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/cards#spaces). They are the Chat API equivalent of a [chatroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chat_room). In fact the resource [`rooms`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/rooms) is a special subset of `spaces`. Then, if you want to create a `space` you only need to work with [`spaces.message.create()`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create). Please keep in mind that Chat API is geared towards bots, and bots don't create chatrooms (they are invited by users to existing chatrooms). Feel free to comment on my answer if you have any doubts.